# Allow logged in user to edit their information - PHP / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I apologise if this question has been asked, I have looked and can't find an answer that fits but if I'm wrong please tell me!

I've created a login form and when the user logs in they can see their Name, E-mail, Phone and Availability. At the moment this is just echoing / printing the information from the MySQL database. What I was wondering is how I make this editable so that the logged in user can update their own information?

Thanks an absolute bunch to everyone by the way, I'm new to this site and everyone has been extremely helpful. I'm not a developer by trade and very much learning as I go on this project so it is appreciated! :)

```
<?php
session_start();
$sessData = !empty($_SESSION['sessData'])?$_SESSION['sessData']:'';
if(!empty($sessData['status']['msg'])){
$statusMsg = $sessData['status']['msg'];
$statusMsgType = $sessData['status']['type'];
unset($_SESSION['sessData']['status']);
}
?>
<div class="container">
<?php
    if(!empty($sessData['userLoggedIn']) && !empty($sessData['userID'])){
        include 'user.php';
        $user = new User();
        $conditions['where'] = array(
            'id' => $sessData['userID'],
        );
        $conditions['return_type'] = 'single';
        $userData = $user->getRows($conditions);
?>
<h2>Welcome <?php echo $userData['first_name']; ?>!</h2>
<a href="userAccount.php?logoutSubmit=1" class="logout">Logout</a>
<div class="regisFrm">
    <p><b>Name: </b><?php echo $userData['first_name'].' '.$userData['last_name']; ?></p>
    <p><b>Email: </b><?php echo $userData['email']; ?></p>
    <p><b>Phone: </b><?php echo $userData['phone']; ?></p>
<p><b>Available: </b><?php echo $userData['available']; ?></p>

<li><a href=profile.php>Update Profile<a></li><br>

<form action="change.php" method="post">
Are you available this weekend?<br>
<input type="radio" name="available" value="yes"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="available" value="no"> No<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

</div>
<?php }else{ ?>
<h2>Login to Your Account</h2>
<?php echo !empty($statusMsg)?'<p class="'.$statusMsgType.'">'.$statusMsg.'</p>':''; ?>
<div class="regisFrm">
    <form action="userAccount.php" method="post">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL" required="">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="PASSWORD" required="">
        <div class="send-button">
            <input type="submit" name="loginSubmit" value="LOGIN">
        </div>
    </form>
    <p>Don't have an account? <a href="registration.php">Register</a></p>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: `<li><a href=profile.php?id=<?php echo $sessData['userID'];?>>Update Profile<a></li>` then on profile show details of the user in a editable form

Comment: You seem to already know how forms work - so what is the actual question here? How to pre-fill form fields with the current values? value attribute for normal text inputs, between the opening and closing tag for textarea, checked/selected for checkbox, radio buttons and select options ...

Comment: Thanks for responses for everybody, I can easily make a form and I can submit and it creates a new record. Please don't underestimate my lack of knowledge here! My problem is getting the submitted form to update the logged in user.

Comment: Save your fetch ID on session and on your profile.php create another form. that UPDATE your details using mysql query and use the session_id for the where clause..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a newbie to php programming as well, so I very well could be wrong. I apologize in advance if this doesn't work. 
From what I understand of your question, why can't you make a form?
I was in a similar situation before, and I just made a form asking for their details they wish to change and a password field. 
Transfer the data from the form to a .php file (using action='filename.php'), where you can make queries to update your mysql database.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Vamshi I appreciate your answer, I guess my problem is I don't know how this become editable and submits against that user. I can make the form so it creates a new row in the table but not update an existing one.

Comment: oh you want the sql query? sure, give me a minute

Comment: Update table_name set name=$name, phonenumber=$phonenumber where primarykey=$primarykey

Essentially, you'll have to use the update command. Go through this link for more details
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: Vamshi you're a legend! Thanks to everybody for your help!

Comment: If it worked, accept the answer. It'll let others at stack exchange know that your problem is solved. And I am a newbie too, so always ready to help. Cheers!

Comment: I'm that much of a newbie I didn't know I could accept an answer lol, done now cheers!